# *** No targets. Stop on Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, makefile, target

This is a very basic program because I am using Make and Linux both for the first time. I have seen other questions similarly and I have tried all: *.o 
all: *.c
And clean : rm *.o h1
[image]
And here is the directory
[image]

Comment: It's considered bad SO form to post pictures - text is better.  But in the makefile, are the indented lines with spaces or tabs? They have to be tabs.

Comment: @SteveFriedl       The gcc are all indented with tabs. Also sorry I just figured pictures were easier for everyone.

Comment: How are pictures easier for anyone but you? Lots of posts get downvoted for posting screenshots, but you actually posted a *picture of your screen*... amazing.

Comment: There's no reason not to take the OP at their word that they thought they were trying to be helpful. They were mistaken, but not malicious or lazy.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart  I simply figured in terms of coding showing is normally better then explaining. If it makes you feel better to put me down because of it, I hope you never make any mistakes as you must be extremely hard on yourself.

Comment: Alexis, you should copy/paste/correctly format the code and listing here, instead of using images.

Comment: @ Carl Norum I will next time, I believe I have for all my previous questions however I did not know this was a rule. Unfortunately I am not working from home and had my roommate send me the pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a file called `makefile` and one called `Makefile`. Delete the one that doesn't have any contents.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I'm just used to Netbeans so a text file is all new. I have to wait a couple minutes to accept your answer but thanks again!